# Nested attribute doesn't show up attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, attr-accessible, authenticity-token

I have a nested attribute message.rb

```
  class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :trip  
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :subject, :body
  end
```

Which belongs trip.rb

```
  class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :messages_attributes
  end
```

messages_controller.rb

```
  class MessagesController < ApplicationController   
   def create
     @trip = Trip.find(params[:trip_id])
     @message = @trip.messages.create(params[:message])
     redirect_to trip_path(@trip)
   end
  end
```

Message form is in the \trips\show.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for([@trip, @trip.messages.build]) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :name%><br />
     <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :email %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :email %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subject %><br />
   </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
   </div>

   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
   <% end %>
```

And it should appear there as well \trips\show.html.erb

```
   <h2>Messages</h2>
     <% @trip.messages.each do |message| %>
   <p>
   <b>NAme:</b>
     <%= message.name %>
   </p>
    <b>Email:</b>
     <%= message.email %>
   </p>
     <b>Subject:</b>
     <%= message.subject %>
   </p>
     <b>Message:</b>
     <%= message.body %>
   </p>
   <% end %>
```

The problem is that it just doesn't.

My Development.log.

> Started GET "/trips/44?  utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=%2F0Qs42AHHm9dpO17xfJsu5LSaYCKIschXu3boFjRg54%3D&message> %5Bname%5D=emils&message%5Bemail%5D=emils.veveris%40inbox.lv&message%5Bsubject%5D=aasdasda> ds&message%5Bbody%5D=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&commit=Create+Message" for 127.0.0.1 at  2012-07-31 23:11:16 +0300
>    Processing by TripsController#show as HTML
>    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"/0Qs42AHHm9dpO17xfJsu5LSaYCKIschXu3boFjRg54=", "message"=>>>> >  {"name"=>"emils", "email"=>"emils.veveris@inbox.lv", "subject"=>"aasdasdads",  "body"=>"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}, "commit"=>"Create Message", "id"=>"44"}
>     [1m[35mTrip Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."id" = ? LIMIT  1  [["id", "44"]]
>    [1m[36mCategory Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN  "categories_trips" ON "categories"."id" = "categories_trips"."category_id" WHERE  "categories_trips"."trip_id" = 44[0m
>    [1m[35mLocation Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE>   "locations"."id" = 18 LIMIT 1
>    [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."id" = ? LIMIT   1[0m
>    [1m[35mImage Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."trip_id" = 44
>    [1m[36mMessage Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."trip_id" = 44[0m
>    [1m[35mAccomodation Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "accomodations".* FROM "accomodations" WHERE "accomodations"."trip_id" = 44
>    [1m[36mLesson Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "lessons".* FROM "lessons" WHERE "lessons"."trip_id" = 44[0m
>    [1m[35mDetail Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "details".* FROM "details" INNER JOIN "details_trips" ON "details"."id" = "details_trips"."detail_id" WHERE "details_trips"."trip_id" = 44
>    [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1[0m
>   Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.2/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb (1.0ms)
>    [1m[35mReview Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "reviews".* FROM "reviews" WHERE "reviews"."trip_id" = 44
>   Rendered trips/show.html.erb within layouts/application (261.0ms)
>   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
>   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (3.0ms)
>   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 404ms (Views: 295.0ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)

I don't really understand why, I kinda did set attr_accessible. Can You help ?
Thank You!

### **Update**

via rails console it works:

> irb(main):019:0> first_trip.messages.create(name: "emils2")
>    ←[1m←[35mSQL (2.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "created_at", "email
>   ", "name", "subject", "trip_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["
>   body", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 01 Aug 2012 13:52:29 UTC +00:00], ["email", nil
>   ], ["name", "emils2"], ["subject", nil], ["trip_id", 32], ["updated_at", Wed, 01
>   Aug 2012 13:52:29 UTC +00:00]]
>
> 32, created_at: "2012-08-01 13:52:29", updated_at: "2012-08-01 13:52:29">

And my routes.rb nested as well:

```
resources :trips do
 resources :messages
end
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the message models get saved into the database? Use for example rails console `rails c`.

Comment: Does your routes file contain the nested resources, too?  (example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources)

Comment: Yes, the message gets saved in db via console and my route file contains nested resources ...

Comment: Still can't get trough this ..

Comment: I meant that after you have created a message through the form you should check from the console if it actually is in the database.

Comment: No, after the form it is not saved in the db.