# Submitting multiple rows into a database using a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've created a rails app where a user chooses their preference between different vegetables. The database is formatted as follows:

- Prefid (key)
- Userid
- veg1
- veg2
- preference

The form follows a format --

```
<%= form_for :pick do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select( :id, Players.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= f.radio_button(pref.id, veg.veg1) %>
<%= f.radio_button(pref.id, veg.veg2) %> 
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Right now, when the form is submitted, I have this as my create method --

```
def create
    @prefs = Prefs.new()
    @prefs[:player_id] = post_params[:id]
    post_params.delete(:id)
    post_params.each do |key, value|
        @prefs.games_id = key
        @prefs.pick = value 
        @prefs.save
    end

    redirect_to @picks
end
```

This method doesn't work. It only submits the first pick into the database. I've read a few different ways to do this, but none of them really follow the same format as my application.

Comment: you might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources

Comment: and this http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually?autoplay=true