# NoMethodError when breaking validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

We are talking about a minimalistic nested `Comment's Controller`.

the validation is `validates :body, :presence => true`

Now, editing a comment works, and if i create a new comment and break the validation it is shown normally.

**My Problem** is when i EDIT a comment and delete his body, NORMALLY i should get an error about the Body, instead i get a `NoMethodError in Comments#update`

**Problem Extension =>**  Normally when i successfully edit a Comment `(http://localhost:3000/s/38/comments/11/edit)` it redirects me to @screen `http://localhost:3000/s/38`. But if i empty the body and try to submit, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/s/38/comments/11` instead of showing me the errors.

[image]

What am i missing ?

The Controller:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.update(comment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @comment.screen, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My Edit Form:

```
<%= form_for([@screen, @comment]) do |f| %>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h1>Edit your Comment</h1>
      <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h3><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being saved:</h3>

          <ul>
            <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body, "Comment" %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
      <%= f.submit "Edit Comment", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Back", @screen, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

My Routes:

```
resources :screens, :path => 's' do
    resources :comments
    member do
      get :like
      get :unlike
    end
  end
```

```
    screen_comments GET    /s/:screen_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /s/:screen_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
  new_screen_comment GET    /s/:screen_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
 edit_screen_comment GET    /s/:screen_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
      screen_comment GET    /s/:screen_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /s/:screen_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /s/:screen_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /s/:screen_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

Comment: Can you also show the relevant routes definition?

Comment: could you do `rake routes` and verify if there exists that route?

Comment: The Comments are nested, so comments_path should be screen_comments as in the rake routes.. But i have no idea what went wrong here :(

Comment: You could watch at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources

Comment: Interesting Answer, but i did not get how this help's me in my situation ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form for using the polymorphic routes like that will always use the pluralized path for new records. I needed to be explicit in my form:

```
form_for([@user, @profile], :url => user_profile_path(@user))
```