# Nested forms fail when using an ActiveResource model, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I have problem with creating a form for my ActiveResource models but I can't seem to find a solution. The problem is that the model does not know the fields, and throws an error when I try to create a text field:

```
undefined method `firstname' for #<User:0x00000002946ec8>
```

For this form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :firstname %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
 </div>
```

This is my from my controller:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

Thie is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "https://***.com/api/v1.0/"
end
```

I tried the following, but that does not work well with ActiveResource models, it is somehow not able to store retrieved data anymore. user.firstname is empty, when i remove the line it is not...

```
attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname
```

Then I found the gem Fortify (https://rubygems.org/gems/fortify) but the last update was in 2010 and installing it doesn't work...

I hope someone is familiar with this problem and can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources

Double check the app routes.

Comment: can you list your User model?

Comment: @maximus, I edited my post and added the user model. At BaraaAl-Bourghli, I don't think it's related.

Comment: @Chris could you please go to `rails console` type `User` and show the output? I suspect that you might forgot to create `firsname` field when you were generating User model.

Comment: @LukasMac, this is an ActiveResource model. There is not real model, it goes over REST API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `.build`[1] in your controller instead of `.new`[2], like:

```
@user = User.build
```

The reason is that `.new` with no params just creates an empty object, whereas `.build` first queries the api for what params it should be using, specifically for this usecase ([see this thread for more details](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4155-activeresource-generates-an-error-for-a-form_for-attribute#ticket-4155-5))

Docs:

1. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-build
2. http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html#method-c-new

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it throws a 500 server error from the remote API. Do you know what kind of response it is expecting or what kind of request it makes? Should I prepare the API in a way?

Comment: It's making a call to `"https://***.com/api/v1.0/users/new.json` and it's expecting a valid json response with the attributes of a new user  (from which it will populate the form).  ActiveResource expects the API to be RESTful, but if your API is throwing a 500 then maybe it isn't - you should investigate what caused the 500 error at the other end and read up on REST if you aren't sure about it ([this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217758/what-is-a-rest-api) is a good place to start.