# Ruby on Rails, ActionView UrlHelper link_to new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have two models "projectaim" and "tender", relation:

```
class Projectaim < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tenders
end
```

... almost standard controllers

... and views:
lets say that master object `@projectaim` is already created.

On its edit view edit.html.erb I have to make a link to create subordinate `@tender` on separate form:

```
 <% @tender.projectaim_id = @projectaim.id %>
 <%=link_to "Add new tender", new_tender_path(@tender)%>
```

Could you please advise me how to parametrize new tender action (or view) to hold relation based on models? Technically I need to fill tender.projectaim_id item in new tender action? Thanks to all.

Comment: Nested resources is your friend.

Comment: thanks for help, now Im studying nested resources. Seems understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) in this case.

Your routes file would look something like this

```
resources :projectaims do
  resources :tenders
end
```

and you would make a link like this

```
<%=link_to "Add new tender", new_projectaim_tender_path(@projectaim, @tender)%>
```

Inside your controller you will now have params[:projectaim_id] in addition to params[:id].

Comment: Great hint, thank you very much for information. Now Im trying to edit controller and views manually with parial success. Tell me please, is there any way to regenerate them because params and form_for? Thakns.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you if you need to get form_for helper working with nested resources you can check out this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources

Comment: I thing you understand me well, the post is valuable. I have to edit proper controller and views manually. The principles is that both objects should be created in tenders controller (@projectaim and @tenders) and then I can use it on tenders form form_for([@projectaim, @tenders]). I have to customize controller an params manually, there is probably not any automation if generating scaffolds. Thank you for help.

Comment: Great, feel free to mark the answer as correct if your issue has been resolved :) thanks

Comment: It looked like url helper issue In the beginning, then I found that I need nested resources and controllers customizations. great post about this issue is here [link](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/3074080)