# How do I create a new/create action for items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails assignment that asks that I create a list of items. I created the controller and model for item, but am still having some trouble. I keep receiving the following error:

```
undefined method `items_path' for
```

Here is some of my code:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params.require(:item).permit(:name))
     if @item.save
       flash[:notice] = "Item was saved."
       redirect_to @item
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the item. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
   end
end
```

Items Model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

New.html.erb in items

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :items, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  get 'welcome/index'
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
end
```

Item.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are using `form_for @item` in your views, is that right? Adding the relevant code might improve the question, but the issue seems to be clear.

Comment: Yup just added the view, sorry about that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :users do
    resources :items, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

This will nest items route inside user. Check `rake routes` and you will not get this `items_path`

You have to define `resource :items` to get `items_path`

So if you want to use nested routes you have to update your form and controller and if not just routes `resource :items`

```
<%= form_for [@user, @item] do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

and controller

```
def new
    @item = Item.new
    @user = current_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You've nested your items resource under users. It should be *user_items_path*.

Answer (score 0):

The items are nested under users, so they always must have a corresponding user. Example `/users/1/item/3`

If the logged user is the one creating items, your form should look like this:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @item] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

If you can create items for other users, you have to create a `@user` instance in the new action of the controller and then change `current_user` for `@user`

Comment: `current_user` is a devise created variable with the logged user.