# In rails, how to create forms for routes which are members of a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a form for "Comments" route which is a member of Article Resources:

```
 resources :articles do
  member do
   post 'comments'
  end
 end
```

I want the comment form to be in Articles#Show page. The problem i got an error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

If the for is like this:

```
<div>
  <%= form_for @comm do |c| %>
  <%= c.label :Your_comment %>
  <%= c.text_area :commBody %>
  <%= c.submit 'submit' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**So how to do it ?**

Comment: Can you post your articles_controller?

Comment: It is too long. Which Actions you need to know?

Comment: `def show
    @art = Article.find(params[:id])
  end`

Comment: Try adding `@comm = Comment.new` to the show action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [form\_for with nested resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources)

Comment: yes adding @comm solved the problem but it still I need details how to pass information form these members(routes)

Answer (score 1):

If this is your controller,

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

and you want to create a form for a new `Comment` related to `@article` that points to `POST /articles/3/comments`:

```
<%= form_for([@article, Comment.new], as: :article, url: comments_article_path(@article)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :body %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments` in the `Article` model. And also don't forget to setup the whitelisted params in the `ArticleController`.

Another thing: don't use abbreviations for your variable names. Use `@article` and `@comment`, not `@art` and `@comm`.

Comment: Thanks @zwippie. I did it and it is working. I did tried it without ACCEPT_NESTED method and it is also working. So what is the disadvantage if I do not use this method?

Answer (score 1):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles do
   post :comment, on: :member #-> url.com/articles/:id/comment
end

#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @article = Article.find params[:id]
      @comment = @article.comments.new
   end
end

#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
Comment:
<%= form_for [@article, @comment], url: article_comment_path(@article) do |c| %>
   <%= c.label "Your Comment" %>
   <%= c.text_area :commBody %>
   <%= c.submit %>
<% end %>
```