# Rails nested routing prefix verb issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes, nested-resources

My app works as intended, however I have a question in regards to nested routes. In my routes file I have

```
resources :lists do
    resources :items
end
```

and when I run rake:routes I get(shortened to save space)

```
list_items     GET    /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#index
               POST   /lists/:list_id/items(.:format)          items#create
new_list_item  GET    /lists/:list_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
edit_list_item GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
list_item      GET    /lists/:list_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
```

When I follow tutorials or other material, their 'Prefix Verb' would only have ***action*_item** (i.e new_item) and the forms would only have

```
form_for @item
```

instead of what I have

```
form_for [@list, @item]
```

I was wondering if I was missing something, or doing something wrong. Any help or information is appreciated.

Comment: What you have is correct. [Here's another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4611932/2272894) that goes over what you have already.

Comment: Awesome. Just wanted a clarification I guess. Maybe I wasn't paying too much attention when reading some resources. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the tutorial isn't using nested routes. Within your routes you are defining the resources of items within the resources of list (resources are defined based on the RESTful routes)

So when

```
form_for [@list, @item]
```

is used it knows that to generate the form it recognizes that it is a nested route and the routes with a route that extends to something like '/lists/:list_id/items/:item_id' it needs two ids to know which route to POST to.

If the tutorial had

```
form_for [@item]
```

it isn't a nested route so the routes are most likely

resources :items
and would generate routes without the lists (i.e. new_item => '/item/item_id')
Thats why your routes have the lists included in the prefix verb.

I am on my phone right now. I will fix the typos and structure in a bit when I get to my computer.

Comment: That's what I thought initially. Just wanted to make sure what I was doing was right. Thanks for the help :)