# rails form_for ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `journals_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a journal model for every user.

In routes.rb I have:

```
resources :users do
  resources :journals
end
```

In user model:

```
has_many :journals
```

In journals model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

When try to use form_for(journal) I get:

```
undefined method `journals_path'
```

I do not know how fix this.

form_for the first line:

```
<%= form_for(journal) do |f| %>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527271/using-form-for-with-nested-resources

Comment: The link helped. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a nested resource, you have to include parent `user` like this:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @journal] do |f| %>
```

To get the correct path