# Rails 5: Associated relation triggers create instead of update on edit view

Tags: rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, belongs-to

I started with the guide on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I successfully get it up and running. So far I made a few adjustments (like naming of the controller, etc.). This tutorial didn't cover how to update the relations of a model and this is the point I'm currently struggling.

models/game.rb

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :achievements, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

models/achievement.rb

```
class Achievement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
end
```

The update of my games, work like a charm.

controller/game_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
end

    def update
            @game = Game.find(params[:id])

            if @game.update(game_params)
                redirect_to @game
            else
                render 'edit'
            end

        end

    private
            def game_params
                params.require(:game).permit(:title, :total_gs_points)
            end
```

So I tried to transfer it to my achievements

controller/achievements_controller.rb

```
def edit
        @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
        @achievement = @game.achievements.find(params[:id])
end

def update
        @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
        @achievement = @game.achievements.find(params[:id])
        # @achievement = Achievement.find(params[:id])

        if @achievement.update(achievement_params)
            redirect_to game_achievements_path(@game)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

end

private
        def achievement_params
            params.require(:achievement).permit(:id, :title, :description, :status, :hint, :pinned, :gs_points)
        end
```

But there, every time I call my edit route, it fires a create event.

```
Started GET "/games/1/achievements/3/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-06 15:57:45 +0200
Processing by AchievementsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"game_id"=>"1", "id"=>"3"}
  Game Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `games`.* FROM `games` WHERE `games`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Achievement Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `achievements`.* FROM `achievements` WHERE `achievements`.`game_id` = 1 AND `achievements`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Rendering achievements/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered achievements/_form.html.erb (3.2ms) [cache miss]
  Rendered achievements/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (8.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 23.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

My included form _form.html.erb in views/achievements/edit.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= form_for([@game, @game.achievements.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :status %><br>
        <%= f.select :status, options_for_select([ 'open', 'claimed' ], 'open') %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :hint %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :hint %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :pinned %><br>
        <%= f.check_box :hint %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :gs_points %><br>
        <%= f.select :gs_points, options_for_select([ 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100 ], 50) %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

On my edit.html.erb, I get the correct achievement information, but don't know why the fields are not getting prefilled. The Submit buttons text is every time "Create achievement"

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Achievement: <%= @achievement.title %></h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', game_achievements_path(@game) %>
```

Thanks & Regards,
mybecks

Answer (score 0):

What does your routes file look like? You may be able to just do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @achievement do |f| %>
< your form code >
```

Based on your update method Rails should be able to find the achievement associated with the specific game. I'm not 100% sure though, let me know if this works for you. 
Edit:
You can probably do something in routes like this:

```
resources :games do
    resources  :achievements 
end
```

Comment: my `routes.rb` file looks exactly like yours. I also tried your form_for variant, but with that, I'm not able to create 'games' ... and if I run that on an existing achievement, then the edit screen didn't change.

Comment: @mybecks I think I may have misunderstood your question. Using "@game.achievements.build" creates a new achievement linked to the game. You might be able to try something like this for the form:  "<% form_for ([@game, @achievement]) do |f| %>". Check out this answer where someone was having a similar problem to what you're encountering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034700/form-for-with-nested-resources

Comment: thanks for poinitng out that link. I finally got it working, following line did the trick. `<%= form_for([@game, @achievement||= @game.achievements.build ]) do |f| %>`

Comment: @mybecks No problem, I'm glad it helped! Learning RoR can be really annoying when you first start.